# 100% Browser Width Images with Rails 4 App

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4, and Bootstrap 3. In my application.html.erb I have  to keep the content on my home page in a container, but if I move my end `</div>` above the `<%= yield %>` then I can keep the content outside of it full width and not in the Bootstrap container. In order to have specific full width items on all of my pages, do I have to put a `<div class="container">` in every view of my rails app? Or, is there a better way?

```
 <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>
   <%= yield %>
   <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

I want to make content be in a 960px grid, like `<div class="container">` except I want other content in the same dynamic template to be outside the container like Medium does with their full width images in contrast to the text that is in a container. See below:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one container. Use 'row' inside of containers and then 'col' inside of 'row'. See bootstrap docs on how to layout your pages.

Comment: But if I use one container in my application.html.erb, how to I get content outside of the 960px(etc) grid? Like a full width image? `class="row"`inside container still keeps the content inside the grid.

Comment: Look at CSS positioning. If you're trying to do like a full page background image. Use html,body. Else check out absolute div positioning. This will bust out of the container. There are other ways .. better way is using JS. You have many options.

Comment: For instance, http://medium.com has full width images inside most of their posts, but the text of their posts are still in a container that limits their width. How can you have both? .. a 960px container that limits text with full-width images next to the text? - but dynamically in a rails 4 app

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't look at their source but I can say with a high degree of confidence that they use JS perhaps jQuery with some sort of lightbox. It's fairly complicated . Can't explain in a comment. Clook up jQuery lightboxes and learn about CSS. What you want to do is all JS and CSS. Nothing to do with bootstrap or rails.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help! I understand lightbox and what jquery can do, but this seems to be an issue with where `<div class="container">` is are placed. See the images I attached in my posts for more clarification.